# Python driver for SQLServer pyodbc much slower than psycopg2 and mysql.connector with inserts

Tags: mysql, sql-server, python-3.x, postgresql, pyodbc

We have an application built in Python which has to run on different databases, e.g. SQLServer, MySQL and Postgres. When we do inserts into SQL Server using the pyodbc library this is much slower (20 times!) than when doing the same inserts into Postgres using psycopg2 or into MySQL using mysql.connector. I have two questions:
1. What could be the reason of this difference in performance?
2. What could we do (apart from using Postgres/MySQL) ?

Comment: psycopg2 has disabled autocommit by default. Maybe pyodbc use autocommit mode.

Comment: Hi Pavel, thx, but we have autocommit also on in psycopg2.

Comment: For MySQL are you using MySQL Connector/Python or MySQL Connector/ODBC?

Comment: FWIW, I just tested SQL Server ODBC 11 vs. MySQL Connector/ODBC 5.3 using [fast_executemany](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Features-beyond-the-DB-API#fast_executemany) under pyodbc 4.0.23 and INSERTs to SQL Server were over five times *faster* than MySQL (16,000 rows/second vs. 2,800 rows/second).

Comment: @ Gord I'll try to out, thx!

Answer (score 2):

When MySQL Connector/Python encounters an `executemany` call for an INSERT statement it constructs one or more multi-row INSERTs, thus reducing the number of round-trips to the server. For example,

```python
crsr = cnxn.cursor()
sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (id) VALUES (%s)"
params = [(x,) for x in range(3)]
crsr.executemany(sql, params)
```

sends a single INSERT statement to the MySQL server

```sql
INSERT INTO mytable (id) VALUES (0),(1),(2)
```

By contrast, the default behaviour for pyodbc is to send individual INSERT statements, so

```python
crsr = cnxn.cursor()
sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (id) VALUES (?)"
params = [(x,) for x in range(3)]
crsr.executemany(sql, params)
```

sends the equivalent of

```sql
INSERT INTO mytable (id) VALUES (0)
INSERT INTO mytable (id) VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO mytable (id) VALUES (2)
```

requiring three round-trips to the server instead of just one.

Fortunately, current versions of pyodbc support multi-row INSERTs to SQL Server via the [fast_executemany](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Features-beyond-the-DB-API#fast_executemany) property of the Cursor object, so

```python
crsr = cnxn.cursor()
sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (id) VALUES (?)"
params = [(x,) for x in range(3)]
crsr.fast_executemany = True
crsr.executemany(sql, params)
```

produces essentially the same result as the MySQL Connector/Python example above.